# MongoServerError: not authorized on mydb_db to execute command

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I use `mongo 6.0.7` and I run this command fine:

```
mongosh -u api -p --authenticationDatabase mydb_db
```

and I login with this user fine.

But with the same credentials, my application cannot connect to database and I get `authentication failed` in the logs (it is `nodejs` if matters).

But after login in the cli, I can run `use mydb_db` and it switches fine, but this fails:

```
rs0 [direct: primary] mydb_db> db.getUsers()
MongoServerError: not authorized on mydb_db to execute command { usersInfo: 1, lsid: { id: UUID("6bcc1743-9303-4ad4-a136-bc0b7bf0e1b8") }, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1704272881, 1), signature: { hash: BinData(0, 62E80733C0FCF60FE333934D8E6796C319B16B99), keyId: 7264672765817389063 } }, $db: "mydb_db" }
rs0 [direct: primary] mydb_db> show users
MongoServerError: not authorized on mydb_db to execute command { usersInfo: 1, lsid: { id: UUID("6bcc1743-9303-4ad4-a136-bc0b7bf0e1b8") }, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1704272881, 1), signature: { hash: BinData(0, 62E80733C0FCF60FE333934D8E6796C319B16B99), keyId: 7264672765817389063 } }, $db: "mydb_db" }
rs0 [direct: primary] mydb_db> show dbs
mydb_db  5.50 MiB
```

The database is not new, and it's been working for months. Last day I changed the password of `api` user.

Still I can login but this is what I have as error.

**Update 1**

contents of `.env` file:

```
NODE_ENV=production
MONGO_URI_LOCAL=mongodb://localhost:27017/
MONGO_URI_SERVER=mongodb://api:myNewPassword@localhost:27017/
DB_NAME=mydb_db
DB_USERNAME=api
DB_PASSWORD=myNewPassword
```

Comment: Does the new password contain any special characters, i.e. one of `$ : / ? # [ ] @`? Use `urlencode()` or `encodeURIComponent()` to escape them.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit no, I use only `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

Answer (score 1):

You asked similar question already. I suspect, you updated the wrong user.

You can check all defined users in your database with this command (to be executed with an admin account).

```
db.getSiblingDB('admin').getCollection('system.users').find()
```

Have a careful look in which database the users are created and on which user you changed the password. Personally I don't know any reason why a user should be created in any other database than `admin`.

You may also have a look at [Authentication failure while trying to save to mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470)

Comment: Thanks, yes I asked the similar question but it was fixed that day. Again I'm seeing the issue and not sure why. I even didn't change anything. I see I created user in the right database. But I'll created the user under `admin` database and will inform you.

Comment: I ran `db.dropUser('api')`, then `use admin; db.createUser` and roles are `dbOwner, db: 'mydb_db`. I have everything in another database.

Comment: Now with `use admin`, when I run `show users`, I see a user called `admin.api` and the roles are `role: 'dbOwner', db: 'mydb_db'`. In the `nodejs` I still have `authentication failed`. I'll update the question regarding the `.env` file.

Comment: What is (or was) the current database when you run `db.dropUser('api')`? Did you grant anything else? `{ role: 'dbOwner', db: 'mydb_db' }` does not grant `db.getUsers()` on `admin`

Comment: Regarding connection see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470 as I already mentioned.

Comment: I was first on `mydb_db` and dropped the user. Then I ran `use admin; show users` and `admin` database has one user which is `admin`. Now I created a user under `admin` database.

Comment: I see this error in the mongodb error log file: `error":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"api\" for db \"mydb_db\""` which is true because `mydb_db` doesn't have any users.

Comment: Regarding connection: I can run `mongo -u user -p pwd --authenticationDatabase admin myDB` and it connects in the cli:(

Comment: Just to add and to close: there were some old env vars in `.bashrc` file which caused issue:( It is solved now.